# React native specific style item in map

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, coding-style, react-redux

I have this code that generates buttons for size as come from API like (al, l, m, s ... ) and I need to put a specific style when user click in one circle, I have tried this code but it makes the same style for all circles and I need to change the style for one circle when clicked on it :

```js
<View style={{ paddingTop: 10, width: "49%" }}>
                <View style={styles.sizeView}>
                  <View style={styles.sizeView3}>
                    <Text style={styles.chartText}>{t("size")}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sizeButtons}>
                  {this.state.productsList[0].sizes.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        key={index}
                        onPress={() => this.toggle1(item)}
                        style={
                          !this.state.pressStatus
                            ? styles.sizes
                            : styles.sizesAlt
                        }
                        onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
                        onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}
                      >
                        <Text
                          key={index}
                          style={
                            !this.state.toggle1 ? {} : { color: "#EC1C24" }
                          }
                        >
                          {item}
                        </Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
```

I drag pic for the result
[image]

Comment: Can u upload all of your component code?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri I updated it 
and this the toogle1 function:   toggle1(size) {
    this.setState({ size });
  }

Comment: You're only giving it the color red `#EC1C24` in your  `onPress={() => this.toggle1(item)}`. You're not changing the color in that. You're only changing the size.

Comment: no, all circles have no red border, and I need when user clicking in on of these circle change the style, just for one circle that clicked. My code change the style for all circles when clicking on one of them! :( @OrthoHomeDefense

Comment: I was just pointing out the error. Instead of `style={
                            !this.state.toggle1 ? {} : { color: "#EC1C24" }
                          }` You need to change the style of that element in the `onPress` event

Comment: how can I do it? @OrthoHomeDefense

Comment: You're going to have to put a little effort. It's pretty basic programming. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+native+change+style+onPress

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using one variable to change the toggle status for all the buttons (this.state.toggle1), so if one is toggle they will all be toggled, as i don't think this is the intended behavior.
I suggest to create a pure component for the buttons so that each will have it's own state and handle the toggle independetly.

as for the style, they are 2 syntax working :

```
 style={  !this.state.toggle ? {} : { color: "#EC1C24", backgroundColor: 'red' }}
```

or

```
  style={[ this.state.toggle && {color: "#EC1C24", backgroundColor: 'red'} ]}
```

So first create a component for the circle button

```
export class CircleButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       toggled: false
     };
 }
 render() {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => this.toggle1(item)}
                    style={
                      !this.state.pressStatus
                        ? styles.sizes
                        : styles.sizesAlt
                    }
                    onHideUnderlay={this.props.onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
                    onShowUnderlay={this.props.onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}
                  >
                    <Text
                      key={index}
                      style={
                        !this.state.toggle ? {} : { color: "#EC1C24" }
                      }
                    >
                      {item}
                    </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   );
 }
}
```

And Change your View to something like this

```
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, width: "49%" }}>
            <View style={styles.sizeView}>
              <View style={styles.sizeView3}>
                <Text style={styles.chartText}>{t("size")}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sizeButtons}>
              {this.state.productsList[0].sizes.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <CircleButton  
                     onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
                     onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}/>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
```

Comment: No not like this, all circles have no red border, and I need when user clicking in on of these circle change the style, just for one circle that clicked. My code change the style for all circles when clicking on one of them! :(

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example of how you can do it!